# sox has exited with error code 1 in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sox

I want realtime streaming using Google Cloud Speech to text
I'm running some example code at Google Cloud speech to text document
but this error occurs

```
sox has exited with error code 1.
Enable debugging with the environment variable DEBUG=record.
```

Things I've tried

- Setting Sox environment variables after install sox (14.4-1, 14-4-2) => doesn't work
- Change `recordProgram` value at record option (recordProgram: 'rec' => 'sox') but it doesn't work.
- I found a solution that adds `-t`, `raw` to `cmdArgs` in `node_modules/node-record-lpcm16/index.js` but I couldn't apply it because code is different now.
- Using the node-microphone library but have not been recognized

Operating system: window10

```
language: node js  
dependencies: {  
    "@google-cloud/speech": "^4.1.5",  
    "express": "^4.17.1",  
    "node-microphone": "^0.1.5",  
    "node-record-lpcm16": "^1.0.1"  
  }
```

Codesandbox: [simple source code](https://codesandbox.io/s/stterror-1x9pg?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: did you do this: "_Enable debugging with the environment variable DEBUG=record._"? What was the result?

Comment: It works when I restart the computer
Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

are you working on windows?

try installing sox from:

```
choco install sox.portable
```